# Cpanel righ-mouse menu doesn't work properly

Tags: click, mouse, cpanel, move

Am I the only one who have this issue?

When I click right button on file for a menu AND move my mouse, the menu disappears and selector starts to select.

Can someone help me to fix it?

[image: right click]

[image: mouse move]

Comment: Did try after clearing your browser cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out it was caused by Chrome plugin called "Link Klipper - Extract all links". The plugin has right-click function to select all links on page and I just thought I will check it and yes I was right. If anyone has this issue too, firstly try to disable all of your browser plugins and refresh the page.